# Integer is 0 after being retrieved from C struct

Tags: c, struct

I'm failing to see why the messageSize is printing 0 when calling `removeNode`, especially since it has no problem getting and printing the message. The printf in `insertNode` is printing the size correctly. This might just be a simple oversight. Not sure.

```c
struct qnode {
    char message[256];
    int mesglen;
    struct qnode * next;
};

struct qheader {
    struct qnode * front;
    struct qnode * last;
};

struct qheader queue;

void insertNode() {
    struct qnode newnode;
    char * buffer = "hello";
    strcpy(newnode.message, buffer);
    printf("insert size: %ld\n", strlen(buffer)); // 5
    newnode.mesglen = (int)strlen(buffer);
    struct qnode * curnode = queue.front;
    if (curnode == NULL) {
        queue.front = &newnode;
        queue.last = &newnode;
    } else {
        while (curnode->next != NULL) {
            curnode = curnode->next;
        }
        curnode->next = &newnode;
        queue.last = &newnode;
    }
}

void removeNode() {
    char message[256] = {0};
    int messageSize;
    if (queue.front == NULL) {
        printf("queue empty\n");
    } else {
        strcpy(message, queue.front->message);
        messageSize = queue.front->mesglen;
        queue.front = queue.front->next;
        printf("MESSAGE: %s\n", message);
        printf("MESSAGESIZE: %d\n", messageSize);
    }
}

int main() {
    insertNode();
    removeNode();
    return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
insert size: 5
MESSAGE: hello
MESSAGESIZE: 0
```

Comment: `queue.front = &newnode;` is a pointer to a function local variable - it becomes dangling after the function ends

Comment: Thanks. I'm confused about how to fix that. I can't have a `qnode` as a global variable.

Comment: Look up `malloc` and `free` for allocating memory dynamically

Comment: You want `struct qnode newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct qnode));

Comment: So this has to be done in kernel space eventually. I guess `kmalloc` and `kfree`?

Comment: Answer: yes. These are both working:
`struct * qnode newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct qnode))` and `struct * qnode newnode = kmalloc(sizeof(struct qnode), GFP_ATOMIC)`